# About Alpha blending sprites in Direct3D9

Tags: c++, directx9

I have a Direct3D9 application that is rendering ID3DXSprites. The problem I am experiencing is best described in this situation:

I have a texture that is totally opaque.
On top of it I draw a rectangle filled with solid color and alpha of 128.
On top of the rectangle I have a text that is totally opaque.
I draw all of this and get the resulting image through GetRenderTarget call.
The problem is that on the resulting image, on the area where the transparent rectangle is, I have semi transparent pixels. It is not a problem that the rectangle is transparent, the problem is that the resulting image is.

The question is how to setup the blending so in this situation I don't get the transparent pixels in the resulting image?

I use the sprite with D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND which sets the device state to D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA and D3DBLEND_INVSRCALPHA. I tried couple of combinations of SetRenderState, like D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA, D3DBLEND_DESTALPHA etc., but couldn't make it work.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you paint a transparent rectangle when you want no transparent pixels?

Comment: @vines I want a transparent rectangle over the first texture. But the resultant image shouldn't contain transparent pixels, since the first texture is totally opaque.

Comment: Then it would be nice of you to post the code related to alpha-blending, so that we could check :)

Comment: There's really nothing to it:

m_pSprite->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);
m_pSprite->Draw(m_vecTextures[0].pTexture, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0xffffffff);
m_pSprite->End();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use D3DRS_SEPARATEALPHABLENDENABLE render state to control the blend outcome in the alpha channel of the destination.

```
SetRenderState (D3DRS_SEPARATEALPHABLENDENABLE, TRUE); 
SetRenderState (D3DRS_SRCBLENDALPHA, D3DBLEND_ZERO);
SetRenderState (D3DRS_DESTBLENDALPHA, D3DBLEND_ONE);
```

Provided that your texture was filled with a fully opaque color to begin with; this should leave the alpha channel alone.

Comment: @Aaldert thanks, but that didn't quite work for me. What did work was:  

`SetRenderState (D3DRS_SEPARATEALPHABLENDENABLE, TRUE);`  
`SetRenderState (D3DRS_SRCBLENDALPHA, D3DBLEND_ONE);`  
`SetRenderState (D3DRS_DESTBLENDALPHA, D3DBLEND_ONE);`

Answer (score 1):

for future reference, you should check out Pix in the directx SDK, it's a great tool for seeing exactly what is being rendered at each point, and working out how the final color fo a specific pixel was arrived at.